# SharePoint 2013 Work Flow Assign a Task error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a work flow in share point 2013 onsite. This work flow has one action, and this action is 'Assign a task'.

When the work flow runs it cancels; with the following error:

RequestorId: 3ba82a30-3cc7-4f48-5372-953560e6d97c. Details: System.ArgumentException: OutcomeFieldName at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Can some please tell me what this error means and how to fix it
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was wrong with this scenario.

The list with the Assign Action work flow has a task list associated with it. This associated task list was missing the "Task Outcome" field. I deleted this associated task list and recreated a task list. Associated the newly created task list to the list with the Assign Action work flow. Made sure the associated task list had the 'Task Outcome' field. Ran the work flow and it worked fine.